# Creating a parent and child treeview checkbox nodes

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, treeview, checkbox

I need to create a treeview control with checkboxes. However, my treeview needs to have checkboxes for the parent and the child. *The business logic in my situation is that the user may choose "MS Office" but may not want "Microsoft".*

I came across [asp.net TreeView: how to use CheckBox in TreeView](http://asp-net-example.blogspot.com/2008/12/aspnet-treeview-how-to-use-checkbox-in.html) which helps, however, I can't seem to create a checkbox for "Microsoft" & "Adobe" nodes.  How would I go about doing that?

[image]

**The html code is:**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">  
    <div>  
    <h2 style="color:Green">TreeView: ShowCheckBoxes</h2>  
        <asp:Label   
            ID="Label1"   
            runat="server"   
            Text="Checked Favorite"  
            Font-Size="Medium"  
            ForeColor="SeaGreen"  
            Font-Italic="true"  
            >  
        </asp:Label>  
        <br /><br />  
        <asp:TreeView   
            ID="TreeView1"  
            runat="server"  
            DataSourceID="XmlDataSource1"  
            >  
            <DataBindings>  
                <asp:TreeNodeBinding DataMember="Products" Text="Products" />  
                <asp:TreeNodeBinding DataMember="Type" TextField="Name" />  
                <asp:TreeNodeBinding DataMember="Product" TextField="Name" ValueField="ID" />  
            </DataBindings>  
        </asp:TreeView>  
        <br />  
        <asp:XmlDataSource   
            ID="XmlDataSource1"  
            runat="server"  
            >  
            <Data>  
                <Products>  
                    <Type Name="Microsoft">  
                        <Product ID="1" Name="MS Office"/>  
                        <Product ID="2" Name="ASP.NET"/>  
                    </Type>  
                    <Type Name="Adobe">  
                        <Product ID="1" Name="ColdFusion"/>  
                        <Product ID="2" Name="Flex"/>  
                        <Product ID="2" Name="Photoshop"/>  
                    </Type>  
                </Products>  
            </Data>  
        </asp:XmlDataSource>  
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit Favorite" OnClick="Button1_Click" />  
    </div>  
    </form>
```

**The code behind is:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace TreeviewCheckboxSample
{
    public partial class Treeview : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Label1.Text = "Your favorite:";
            if (TreeView1.CheckedNodes.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (TreeNode node in TreeView1.CheckedNodes)
                {
                    Label1.Text += "<br />" + node.Text.ToString();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Label1.Text = "Checked before submit.";
            }
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!this.IsPostBack)
            {
                TreeView1.ShowCheckBoxes = TreeNodeTypes.Leaf;
                TreeView1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
                TreeView1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
                TreeView1.Width = 200;
                Button1.Font.Bold = true;
                Button1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Crimson;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`ShowCheckBoxes` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treeview.showcheckboxes.aspx) doesn't really cover this case.

However, you can change the [`ShowCheckBox` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treenode.showcheckbox.aspx) on each individual node after the tree is bound. That page contains some example code that even does it based on the node's depth, which looks like what you're after.

Comment: Thanks. "TreeView1.ShowCheckBoxes = TreeNodeTypes.All;" was what I needed.

Comment: Oh, if that works for you, great. I wasn't sure whether or not you wanted one for "Products".